# Sharepoint 2010 Login by another Web Site

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2010, claims-based-identity, fba

I have an urgent need to create a custom login page for a SP2010 site. Now, I know that this can be done by claims-based authentication and FBA but, after several days of work, I couldn't get it done, so I turned for a different approach.

Maybe I can create a front web site with .NET, that will welcome users and authenticate. Then maybe I can set a "session state" for my SP2010 site, and then redirect user to the sp2010 site. I don't know if this is possible any way but I'd like to learn.

I'm open to other suggestions to create custom login pages for SP2010.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the long run, I think you would be better off asking questions that will resolve your issues with CBA and FBA than to hack together a custom single sign on workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had to be able to authenticate a user from a mobile device in SharePoint 2007 and I wanted to create some kind of custom login.

There probably is a much easier/better way to do this than this but I first did something like this with the SharePoint site and then I had to check against active directory.

(User object was some kind of encrypted data over WCF but basically gave the user name and password)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Authenticate whether the user is a user of SharePoint by their username and password
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="LoggedIn">The user that is to be authenticated</param>
    /// <param name="SharePointSiteAddress">The address of the SharePoint site</param>
    /// <returns>The name of the user if they are authenticated or null if not</returns>
    public string AuthenticateSharePointUser_UsePassword(User LoggedIn, string SharePointSiteAddress)
    {
        string nameResult = null;

        try
        {

            Authentication authentication = new Authentication();

            //Check against active directory first
            bool isAuthenticated = authentication.AuthenticateUserActiveDirectory(LoggedIn.GetUserName(), LoggedIn.GetPassword());

            if (isAuthenticated)
            {
                nameResult = authentication.AuthenticateSharePointUserName(LoggedIn.GetUserName(), SharePointSiteAddress);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Authentication Error", ex);
        }

        return nameResult;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Authenticate that a user exists on SharePoint
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="UserName">The username of the user to check</param>
    /// <param name="SiteAddress">The address of the site to check user on</param>
    /// <returns>The name of the user or null if not</returns>
    public string AuthenticateSharePointUserName(string UserName, string SiteAddress)
    {
        string user = null;

        //Open up the site and get the list 
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteAddress))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                try
                {
                    user = web.AllUsers[GetFullDomainUserName(UserName)].Name;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //Swallow exception from the user not existing
                    user = null;
                }
            }
        }
        return user;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Authenticate the user against active directory 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="UserName">The username that can include the domain name domain\username or just username</param>
    /// <param name="Password">The password</param>
    /// <returns>Whether the user has been authenticated</returns>
    public bool AuthenticateUserActiveDirectory(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        //Split on the domain name e.g. domain\...
        string[] splitUserName = GetFullDomainUserName(UserName).Split('\\');
        PrincipalContext context = null;

        bool authenticated = false;

        //Provide user domain if there is one to validate against or use current domain thread is running on
        context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, splitUserName[0]);

        //Now validate against active directory
        using (context)
        {
            authenticated = context.ValidateCredentials(splitUserName[1], Password);
        }

        return authenticated;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a full domain name inclusive username from username given
    /// if there is not already a domain name in it then attach current domain on this machine
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="UserName">The username provided by user</param>
    /// <returns>User name in style e.g. domain\----</returns>
    public static string GetFullDomainUserName(string UserName)
    {
        //Split on the domain name e.g. net\356789
        string[] splitUserName = UserName.Split('\\');

        //If the user gave a domain name then use that domain else use the current domain
        if (splitUserName.Length <= 1)
        {
            splitUserName = new string[] { Environment.UserDomainName, UserName };
        }

        return string.Join("\\", splitUserName);
    }
```